# What is edge and beta?

Tags: snap

I am wondering, what does the "latest/edge" and "latest/beta" mean in snapstore?
I tried looking for answers on the web but I only get MS's Edge browser results. So I thought I could ask here and hopefully get an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Snapcraft](https://snapcraft.io/docs/channels) documented for *beta* and *edge* channels as:

> - beta: for users wanting to test the latest features, typically outside of a production environment.
>
>   Beta is the first level towards the stabilisation of what was before a fast moving stream of changes. Specific projects may have slightly different terminology for such releases (alpha, beta, etc) but all of these are welcome on this risk level. These releases will almost certainly have passed some sort of review and QA, but may still have unfinished parts. Breaking changes are still relatively common here.

> - edge: for users wanting to closely track development.
>
>   Edge releases often include a moving stream of changes without QA or review promises and are typically built automatically by a CI process from an arbitrary source code snapshot. Often the CI will only publish after some sort of automatic QA passed, and code reviews remain a good practice, but these are project specific. Assume edge releases may break often.

So edge is similar to what many projects (Firefox, for example) call nightly builds.